# c# Email Error "System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

Tags: c#, uwp, smtp, visual-studio-2017, mailkit

I get the following error when I reference the class to send an email.

"System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

I'm using
Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.6.6, 
.Net 4.702556 and 
MailKit 2.0.3

I've tried smtp.live.com, smtp.outlook.com, smtp.office365.com, smtp.gmail.com (with a gmail address) and outlook.office365.com

Would anyone know why this error appears and what I can do to get rid of it?

Thanks

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;

namespace Water_Dewater
{
    public class AlarmMessageNotifications
    {
        public static void AlarmEmail()
        {
            var alert = new MimeMessage();
            alert.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("****@hotmail.com"));
            alert.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("****@hotmail.com"));
            alert.Importance = MessageImportance.High;
            alert.Subject = "test";
            alert.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = "testing"
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 587, true);
                client.Authenticate("****@hotmail.com", "****");
                client.Send(alert);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the _full_ error? The text you've provided isn't even an exception type.

Comment: It is a compile-time error, not a runtime error that has anything to do with the specific URL.  You are surely not targeting .NET 4.7. .netcore has a wholeheckofalot of DLL Hell.  Consider https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Security  Or actually targeting 4.7 with the correct project template.  Or dropping "mailkit", nobody really needs a "kit" to send email.

Comment: Actually my error was not knowing the significance of the different project templates and the associated different .Net frameworks.  It is because of your post Hans that I discovered your Feb, 2016 post on the different .Net frameworks.  Thank you for the explanation.
I am programing this in UWP to run on my Raspberry PI.  Based on all of this I'm still foggy on how to correct the error.  I have some reading to do.

Comment: @Bonus9500 What is your uwp app target version and min version? what is the MailKit NuGet version you used?

Comment: Target version Creators Update (10; Build 15063)
Min version (10.0; Build 10240)
MailKit v2.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MailKit 2.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/2.0.3) dependencies requires **System.Net.Security (>= 4.3.0)**, but when you target your app on Creators Update (10; Build 15063) and Min version (10.0; Build 10240), the UWP app used the System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, it doesn't satisfy the requirement.

So try to change your app target version and min version to use the MailKit Nuget.

As a suggestion, since Fall Creators Update(build 16299), UWP support .Net standard 2.0. you can try to target your app on Fall Creators Update(build 16299) and set the Min version build 16299 to use the MailKit v2.0.3.

Comment: That's what did it.  Thanks